# How can I delete a line from a file when the line contains a specific string?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file which is comma separated. I have to find specific text and then delete complete line.

e.g.

```
123,aaa,bbb,888,8881
124,bbb,ccc,999,8881
125,ccc,ddd,888,8883
```

I have to delete the line containing 888.

Comment: Are you using BASH?

Comment: Please explain your question, it's unclear. `888` exist on same line twice. Does that mean you want to get rid of all line wherever `888` found ? or on specific column ? in your case 4th column ?

Comment: `grep -v ',888,'`

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`,

```
sed '/888/d' filename
```

You can use, `-i` option to edit file in-place like,

```
sed -i.bak '/888/d' filename
```

**Note :** `.bak` will keep backup of original file.

---

Assuming, you want to get rid of lines which contains `888` on specific column, then you would want to use,

```
awk -F"," '$4 != "888"' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

```
grep -vw '888' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

If you want to edit inplace,

```
sed -i.bak '/\b888\b/d' infile.csv
```

**Edit:**

To delete lines containing `888` only in 4th column

```
sed -i.bak -r '/^(([^,]+,){3})888,/d' infile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, using `printf` to pipe commands into `ed` is better than `sed -i`.

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/,888,/d' 'w' | ed -s msalik.txt
```

The first arg to `printf` tells it to print each remaining argument separated by newlines (`\n`).

Neither of the last two arguments really need quoting.  I just quoted them as an example - some `ed` commands will need to be quoted.

---

Why is `ed` better than `sed -i`?

Unlike `ed`, `sed -i` doesn't do a true in-place edit.  It creates a temporary output file and then renames it over the original.  This has two potentially unwanted side-effects:

- The permissions on the file may change, due to the `umask` the temp file was created with.  Even the ownership or group may change if the `sed -i` script is run by a different user (who has appropriate RW access to the file and dir, of course).
- The replacement file will have a different inode.  This will break hard links.